# Centering the values of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

**What I am looking for**

I am looking for a way to center the numbers in the dataframe, and to know how to remove the number of the lines in the left section of the table.

**This is my code**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dia da Semana': (semana), 
                   'Glicemia': (NivGlicemia), 
                   'Batimento cardiaco medio': (BatCard)})

print(df)
```

**The image of the table for better comprehension:**

[image: The image of the table for better comprehension]

Comment: just type df and execute your cell. Don't use print.

Comment: Just wanted to make it look prettier, solved it, thanks! And about centering the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just type df and execute your cell. Don't use the print() function.

**Edit**
The [df.style](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html) property can be used to apply conditional formatting of a dataframe
This will work with pandas version 0.17.1 and above.

```
from IPython.display import HTML

styles = [
    dict(selector="th", props=[("text-align", "center")])]

html = (df.style.set_table_styles(styles))
html
```

Comment: This only makes te table look better, doesn't solve the 2 problems I posed. The values left to the table and the values not being centered.

Comment: Where should I add that piece of code? After importing the panda module?

Comment: Anywhere after your dataframe `df` is initialized.

Comment: "ValueError: style is not supported for non-unique indicies."

Comment: Well the style property will not work if you don't have unique indices. Try it without removing your indices.